# WordPress taxonomy radio buttons

Tags: custom-taxonomy, radio

I am trying to change the checkboxes for the terms on the backend to radiobuttons.
I found this topic: [Altering the appearance of custom taxonomy inputs](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7456/altering-the-appearance-of-custom-taxonomy-inputs) however wich helped me doing this.
However, this will turn ALL terms checkboxes to radio buttons.

Is it possible to apply this only for one taxonomy?

My code:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','mysite_add_meta_boxes',10,2);
function mysite_add_meta_boxes($post_type, $post) {
  ob_start();
}
add_action('dbx_post_sidebar','mysite_dbx_post_sidebar');
function mysite_dbx_post_sidebar() {
  $html = ob_get_clean();
  $html = str_replace('"checkbox"','"radio"',$html);
  echo $html;
}
```

thanks

Comment: There's a feature request to build this functionality into WordPress core, which is marked as "accepted" but has been inactive for a while. Might want to chime in / help build it: core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14877

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> However, this will turn ALL terms checkboxes to radio buttons.

Not only that, it'll turn *any* checkbox in a meta box - not ideal!

Instead, let's specifically target the `wp_terms_checklist()` function, which is used to generate the list of checkboxes across the admin (including quick edit).

```
/**
 * Use radio inputs instead of checkboxes for term checklists in specified taxonomies.
 *
 * @param   array   $args
 * @return  array
 */
function wpse_139269_term_radio_checklist( $args ) {
    if ( ! empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) && $args['taxonomy'] === 'category' /* <== Change to your required taxonomy */ ) {
        if ( empty( $args['walker'] ) || is_a( $args['walker'], 'Walker' ) ) { // Don't override 3rd party walkers.
            if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSE_139269_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist' ) ) {
                /**
                 * Custom walker for switching checkbox inputs to radio.
                 *
                 * @see Walker_Category_Checklist
                 */
                class WPSE_139269_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist extends Walker_Category_Checklist {
                    function walk( $elements, $max_depth, ...$args ) {
                        $output = parent::walk( $elements, $max_depth, ...$args );
                        $output = str_replace(
                            array( 'type="checkbox"', "type='checkbox'" ),
                            array( 'type="radio"', "type='radio'" ),
                            $output
                        );

                        return $output;
                    }
                }
            }

            $args['walker'] = new WPSE_139269_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', 'wpse_139269_term_radio_checklist' );
```

We hook onto the `wp_terms_checklist_args` filter, then implement our own custom "walker" (a family of classes used to generate hierarchical lists). From there, it's a simply string replace of `type="checkbox"` with `type="radio"` if the taxonomy is whatever we've configured it to match (in this case "category").

Comment: **Beware**, this is a great answer but poses an issue for Quick Edit. While it does transform quick edit checkboxes into radio buttons it doesn't select the checked radio, it instead clears the list. If you quick-edit you have to check the category each time otherwise it gets removed.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee See my answer for an approach with some additional changes to overcome the limitation.

Comment: Quick edit on category assign value not set. Please guide us

Comment: Here's a little adjustment that needs to be made for WP v5.3 and higher:
`function walk( $elements, $max_depth, ...$args ) {`
`$output = parent::walk( $elements, $max_depth, ...$args );`

Those two lines need to have the ellipses placed in front of the `$args` or it'll throw an error.

I'm going to attempt to edit the answer above...

Comment: There's a feature request to build this functionality into WordPress core, which is marked as "accepted" but has been inactive for a while. Might want to chime in / help build it: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14877

Answer (score 4):

The following does pretty much what @TheDeadMedic did at his [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139277/22534) good answer, brought me there half the way, so this is kind of just an addition to it. Out of personal preference I opted to do it with `start_el`.

→ make sure to replace YOUR-TAXONOMY in below code according to your needs

```
add_filter( 'wp_terms_checklist_args', 'wpse_139269_term_radio_checklist_start_el_version', 10, 2 );
function wpse_139269_term_radio_checklist_start_el_version( $args, $post_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) && $args['taxonomy'] === 'YOUR-TAXONOMY' ) {
        if ( empty( $args['walker'] ) || is_a( $args['walker'], 'Walker' ) ) { // Don't override 3rd party walkers.
            if ( ! class_exists( 'WPSE_139269_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist_Start_El_Version' ) ) {
                class WPSE_139269_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist_Start_El_Version extends Walker_Category_Checklist {
                    public function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
                        if ( empty( $args['taxonomy'] ) ) {
                            $taxonomy = 'category';
                        } else {
                            $taxonomy = $args['taxonomy'];
                        }

                        if ( $taxonomy == 'category' ) {
                            $name = 'post_category';
                        } else {
                            $name = 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';
                        }

                        $args['popular_cats'] = empty( $args['popular_cats'] ) ? array() : $args['popular_cats'];
                        $class = in_array( $category->term_id, $args['popular_cats'] ) ? ' class="popular-category"' : '';

                        $args['selected_cats'] = empty( $args['selected_cats'] ) ? array() : $args['selected_cats'];

                        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/category-template.php */
                        if ( ! empty( $args['list_only'] ) ) {
                            $aria_cheched = 'false';
                            $inner_class = 'category';

                            if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $args['selected_cats'] ) ) {
                                $inner_class .= ' selected';
                                $aria_cheched = 'true';
                            }

                            $output .= "\n" . '<li' . $class . '>' .
                                '<div class="' . $inner_class . '" data-term-id=' . $category->term_id .
                                ' tabindex="0" role="checkbox" aria-checked="' . $aria_cheched . '">' .
                                esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name ) ) . '</div>';
                        } else {
                            $output .= "\n<li id='{$taxonomy}-{$category->term_id}'$class>" .
                            '<label class="selectit"><input value="' . $category->term_id . '" type="radio" name="'.$name.'[]" id="in-'.$taxonomy.'-' . $category->term_id . '"' .
                            checked( in_array( $category->term_id, $args['selected_cats'] ), true, false ) .
                            disabled( empty( $args['disabled'] ), false, false ) . ' /> ' .
                            esc_html( apply_filters( 'the_category', $category->name ) ) . '</label>';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            $args['walker'] = new WPSE_139269_Walker_Category_Radio_Checklist_Start_El_Version;
        }
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Now as @ Howdy_McGee correctly [stated in his comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139269/wordpress-taxonomy-radio-buttons#comment277433_139277) this doesn't work nicely, correctly with the quick/inline edit. The above code handles the saving correctly, but the radio at the inline edit isn't checked. Of course we want that, for this I have done this:

→ write some JQuery code to handle the checked state
→ file name: editphp-inline-edit-tax-radio-hack.js - used below for enqueueing

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var taxonomy = 'status',
        post_id = null,
        term_id = null,
        li_ele_id = null;
    $('a.editinline').on('click', function() {
        post_id = inlineEditPost.getId(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action: 'wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack',
                'ajax-taxonomy': taxonomy,
                'ajax-post-id': post_id
            },
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                term_id = response;
                li_ele_id = 'in-' + taxonomy + '-' + term_id;
                $( 'input[id="'+li_ele_id+'"]' ).attr( 'checked', 'checked' );
            }
        });
    });

});
```

→ we need an AJAX action - as seen in above code block

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack', 'wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack', 'wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack' );
function wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack() {
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms(
        $_POST[ 'ajax-post-id' ],
        $_POST[ 'ajax-taxonomy' ],
        array( 'fields' => 'ids' )
    );
    $result = $terms[ 0 ];
    echo json_encode($result);
    exit;
    die();
}
```

→ enqueueing above script
→ change the path information according to your needs

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack_enqueue_script' );
function wpse_139269_inline_edit_radio_checked_hack_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'editphp-inline-edit-tax-radio-hack-js',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/your/path/editphp-inline-edit-tax-radio-hack.js',
        array( 'jquery' )
    );
}
```

This is working quite nicely so far, **but** only for the first time, when opening the inline edit a second time we have lost the checked state again. We obviously don't want that. To get around it I used a method I've found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/74595/22534) by @brasofilo. What it does is reloading the updated inline edit section. This leads to the radio checkbox being correctly shown, no matter how often it is changed.

→ make sure to replace YOUR-POST-TYPE in below code according to your needs

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_inline-save', 'wpse_139269_wp_ajax_inline_save', 0 );
function wpse_139269_wp_ajax_inline_save() {
    global $wp_list_table;

    check_ajax_referer( 'inlineeditnonce', '_inline_edit' );

    if ( ! isset($_POST['post_ID']) || ! ( $post_ID = (int) $_POST['post_ID'] ) )
        wp_die();

        if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_ID ) )
                wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to edit this page.' ) );
        } else {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_ID ) )
                wp_die( __( 'You are not allowed to edit this post.' ) );
        }

        if ( $last = wp_check_post_lock( $post_ID ) ) {
            $last_user = get_userdata( $last );
            $last_user_name = $last_user ? $last_user->display_name : __( 'Someone' );
            printf( $_POST['post_type'] == 'page' ? __( 'Saving is disabled: %s is currently editing this page.' ) : __( 'Saving is disabled: %s is currently editing this post.' ),    esc_html( $last_user_name ) );
            wp_die();
        }

        $data = &$_POST;

        $post = get_post( $post_ID, ARRAY_A );

        // Since it's coming from the database.
        $post = wp_slash($post);

        $data['content'] = $post['post_content'];
        $data['excerpt'] = $post['post_excerpt'];

        // Rename.
        $data['user_ID'] = get_current_user_id();

        if ( isset($data['post_parent']) )
            $data['parent_id'] = $data['post_parent'];

            // Status.
            if ( isset($data['keep_private']) && 'private' == $data['keep_private'] )
                $data['post_status'] = 'private';
            else
                $data['post_status'] = $data['_status'];

            if ( empty($data['comment_status']) )
                $data['comment_status'] = 'closed';
            if ( empty($data['ping_status']) )
                $data['ping_status'] = 'closed';

            // Exclude terms from taxonomies that are not supposed to appear in Quick Edit.
            if ( ! empty( $data['tax_input'] ) ) {
                foreach ( $data['tax_input'] as $taxonomy => $terms ) {
                    $tax_object = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
                    /** This filter is documented in wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php */
                    if ( ! apply_filters( 'quick_edit_show_taxonomy', $tax_object->show_in_quick_edit, $taxonomy, $post['post_type'] ) ) {
                        unset( $data['tax_input'][ $taxonomy ] );
                    }
                }
            }

            // Hack: wp_unique_post_slug() doesn't work for drafts, so we will fake that our post is published.
            if ( ! empty( $data['post_name'] ) && in_array( $post['post_status'], array( 'draft', 'pending' ) ) ) {
                $post['post_status'] = 'publish';
                $data['post_name'] = wp_unique_post_slug( $data['post_name'], $post['ID'], $post['post_status'], $post['post_type'], $post['post_parent'] );
            }

            // Update the post.
            edit_post();

            $wp_list_table = _get_list_table( 'WP_Posts_List_Table', array( 'screen' => $_POST['screen'] ) );

            $level = 0;
            $request_post = array( get_post( $_POST['post_ID'] ) );
            $parent = $request_post[0]->post_parent;

            while ( $parent > 0 ) {
                $parent_post = get_post( $parent );
                $parent = $parent_post->post_parent;
                $level++;
            }

            $wp_list_table->display_rows( array( get_post( $_POST['post_ID'] ) ), $level );

            if( $_POST['post_type'] == 'YOUR-POST-TYPE' ) {
                ?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        document.location.reload(true);
                    </script>
                <?php
            }

    wp_die();
}
```

*Note:* Not extensively tested, but so far working well

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `meta_box_cb` parameter of the `register_taxonomy` function to define your own function for the `meta_box`. With the help of this [article](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-radio-buttons-with-taxonomies--wp-24779) I have created this snippet:

```
function YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME_meta_box($post, $meta_box_properties){
  $taxonomy = $meta_box_properties['args']['taxonomy'];
  $tax = get_taxonomy($taxonomy);
  $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => 0));
  $name = 'tax_input[' . $taxonomy . ']';
  $postterms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
  $current = ($postterms ? array_pop($postterms) : false);
  $current = ($current ? $current->term_id : 0);
?>
<div id="taxonomy-<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>" class="categorydiv">
  <ul id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-tabs" class="category-tabs">
    <li class="tabs"><a href="#<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-all"><?php echo $tax->labels->all_items; ?></a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>-all" class="tabs-panel">
    <input name="tax_input[<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>][]" value="0" type="hidden">            
    <ul id="<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>checklist" data-wp-lists="list:symbol" class="categorychecklist form-no-clear">
<?php   foreach($terms as $term){
      $id = $taxonomy.'-'.$term->term_id;?>
      <li id="<?php echo $id?>"><label class="selectit"><input value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" name="tax_input[<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>][]" id="in-<?php echo $id; ?>"<?php if( $current === (int)$term->term_id ){?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> type="radio"> <?php echo show_symbol( $term->name ); ?></label></li>
<?php   }?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

To make use of this meta_box, you have to pass this parameter to the `register_taxonomy` function:

```
'meta_box_cb'                => 'YOUR_TAXONOMY_NAME_meta_box'
```

The beauty of this code is that you have to pass in no parameters at all, because it relies on the parameters passed to it by the `register_taxonomy` function. These are the `post` object and an array containing info on the metabox itself.

Comment: Great answer in genral. But beware: You have <?php echo show_symbol( $term->name ); ?> as an output, shouldn't that be <?php echo $term->name; ?>? Couldn't find anything about a function with that name. And as a suggestion: Since you are showing all available categories, you probaly don't need to print out the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather prefer to make it work with a plugin, you might want to take a look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/radio-buttons-for-taxonomies/

This plugin allows you to replace the default taxonomy boxes with a custom metabox that uses radio buttons… effectively limiting each post to a single term in that taxonomy.