# How to restrict on selecting child taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a taxonomy name "City"  .   I have used "city" like this .

```
City 1
    Sub city 1
    Sub city 2
City 2 
    Sub city 3
    Sub city 4
```

Here the problem is if admin/user select City 1 , they can even select  sub city 3 or sub city 4 , which is not under the City 1 . I want to restrict user that they can't select a child taxonomy till they have selected the parent taxonomy .

Or is there any other way , that child taxonomy will appear as drop down , upon selecting parent taxonomy .

Comment: This is a neat problem. You'll probably need both a [Term Walker](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149328/term-checklist-walker-disable-parent-categories) and probably some JS (Or you may be able to do it with JS exclusively). I'll see what I can find!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, you could probably refine this more and come up with better names, I just wanted to make it functional ^_^ !

First thing's first -> Let's include JQuery because I don't want to do this in vanilla JS.

```
function lets_include_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'lets_include_jquery' );
```

Now let's throw a script into the footer of our admin panel to take care of the fun stuff.

```
function lets_add_our_js() {
    if(get_current_post_type() == 'POST_TYPE_HERE') : ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('#TAXONOMY_NAME_HEREchecklist li label > input:checkbox:not(:checked)')
                    .parent('label')
                    .next('ul.children')
                    .css('display', 'none');

                // The following is 100% optional since our children are hidden, I like it though.
                $('#TAXONOMY_NAME_HEREchecklist li label > input:checkbox:not(:checked)')
                    .parent('label')
                    .next('ul.children')
                    .find('input:checkbox')
                    .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                // This is required
                $('#TAXONOMY_NAME_HEREchecklist li label > input:checkbox').click(function(){
                    if($(this).is(':checked')){
                        $(this).parent('label').next('.children').css('display', 'block');
                        $(this).parent('label').next('.children').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('disabled'); // This line is really optional, I like it though.
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).parent('label').next('.children').css('display', 'none');
                        $(this).parent('label').next('.children').find('input:checkbox').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // This line is really optional, I like it though.
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
  <?php endif; 
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'lets_add_our_js');
```

It's a pretty generic script, nothing fancy going on. Next we add a [neat little function I found online](http://themergency.com/wordpress-tip-get-post-type-in-admin/)!

```
function get_current_post_type() {
    global $post, $typenow, $current_screen;

    //we have a post so we can just get the post type from that
    if ( $post && $post->post_type )
    return $post->post_type;

    //check the global $typenow - set in admin.php
    elseif( $typenow )
    return $typenow;

    //check the global $current_screen object - set in sceen.php
    elseif( $current_screen && $current_screen->post_type )
    return $current_screen->post_type;

    //lastly check the post_type querystring
    elseif( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) )
    return sanitize_key( $_REQUEST['post_type'] );

    //we do not know the post type!
    return null;
}
```

---

*Whew*! Now **there are a few things you need to change**... Wherever you find `POST_TYPE_HERE` you'll need to replace that with whatever your post type is so the script will only appear on those admin pages. If you have multiple, is [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). Wherever you see `TAXONOMY_NAME_HERE` you'll want to replace that with the taxonomy name that the metabox holds. So if I create a taxonomy / category called "tax_news" my  Jquery would read: `'#tax_newschecklist'` etc.

**It's Up To You** To rename and comment this code so that it makes sense to you and your scenario for future purposes! I highly suggest you do so!